# Play framework Documentation Task List Example Error

Tags: java, compilation, playframework, playframework-2.0

In Browser:

```
Compilation error

error: cannot find symbol
In /home/william/fmj/app/controllers/Application.java at line 28.

24  public static Result deleteTask(Long id) {

25    return TODO;

26  }

27

28  static Form<Task> taskForm = form(Task.class); 

29
```

In Terminal:

```
[error]   static Form<Task> taskForm = form(Task.class);
[error]               ^
[error]   symbol:   class Task
[error]   location: class Application
[error] /home/william/fmj/app/controllers/Application.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
[error]       views.html.index.render(Task.all(), taskForm)
[error]                               ^
[error]   symbol:   variable Task
[error]   location: class Application
[error] /home/william/fmj/app/controllers/Application.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
[error]   static Form<Task> taskForm = form(Task.class);
[error]                                     ^
[error]   symbol:   class Task
[error]   location: class Application
[error] 3 errors
[error] {file:/home/william/fmj/}fmj/compile:compile: javac returned nonzero exit code
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated. I copy and pasted the code off of the tutorial (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaTodoList) I'm not sure what's going wrong and I'd really like to learn this technology!

Comment: is there a Task class/type in your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you didn't import `Task` model into your `Application` controller

You have 3 solutions:

1. Import each model manually:

   ```
   import models.Task;
   ```
2. import exactly **all** models into your controller (it will be the best at the beginning, but...)

   ```
   import models.*
   ```
3. **Most recommended:** Use some IDE *which knows* **when** and **how to** import required `packages` and `classes` and suggest you what **should be imported** (*or not*)  (ie. [IntelliJ Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) - just suggestion)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think there would be an IDE for Play. Does any Java one work? Eclipse?

Comment: @user1329307: They are not IDEs for Play, they just supports Play better or worse. Eclipse works with play quite well... Idea (Ultimate) works even better. I'm using Idea and it's almost ideal for me - I don't need to care about forgotten imports as IDE informs me about that and suggests the possible choices. There are at least 3 preferred IDEs you can use for easier life with Play: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/IDE

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem (error: cannot find symbol), sure that I have

```
import models.*;
```

but the error is still there.
I'm using eclipse 4.2, and it just suggest create new method `form(Class<Task>`

Comment: Oh my god. Finally I can fix this. Just change the code `static Form<Task> taskForm = form(Task.class);` to `static Form<Task> taskForm = Form.form(Task.class);`

Comment: +1 but the truth isn't in your answer but in your comment. Please correct your post to add `Form.` before `form(Task.class)` to help more people.